# Ambiguity in format of generic in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I encountered Typescript generic in the following format:

```js
export const Form: <FormValues = Record<string, any>, InitialFormValues = Partial<FormValues>>(
  props: FormProps<FormValues, InitialFormValues>
) => React.ReactElement;
```

1. What kind of generic is this?(is it a Generic type or generic function?)
2. If it is generic type (or function) why there is no `=` sign in the code to assign a value to it and why the type being extended has no `Name` like below:

```js
export const Form: Name<FormValues = Record<string, any>, InitialFormValues = Partial<FormValues>> = (
  props: FormProps<FormValues, InitialFormValues>
) => React.ReactElement;
```

3. Generally what is the original type that is being extended by this definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form` is a React function component.  It is a generic `function` which takes a single argument `props` and returns a `ReactElement`.

The type for the `props` argument is `FormProps<FormValues, InitialFormValues>`.  `FormProps` is a generic `interface` which describes a particular type of object.

The function `Form` depends on two generic variables, `FormValues` and `InitialFormValues`, both of which it passes down as the generic variables for `FormProps`.  Both of these generics have default types: `FormValues = Record<string, any>` and `InitialFormValues = Partial<FormValues>`.  The default type for the second variable, `Partial<FormValues>`, depends on the actual type of the first variable `FormValues`.

> why there is no `=` sign in the code to assign a value to it

I'm guessing that this is in a `.d.ts` file?  That is a type declaration file so it just defines the signature of the component, ie. its arguments and return types.

In a regular `.ts` file, you would need to implement the function, not just declare it.

```
export const Form = <FormValues extends {} = Record<string, any>, InitialFormValues = Partial<FormValues>>(
  props: FormProps<FormValues, InitialFormValues>
): React.ReactElement => {
    return (<div/>);
};
```

(that `extends {}` is only there to stop confusion between generics and JSX tags)

`Form` doesn't extend anything, and that's why there is no `Name<...>`.  The original type that is is based off of is a function signature.

Here's a type for a really basic function:

```
type Add = (n: number) => number;
```

Here's a type for a simple generic function:

```
type ReturnSelf = <T>(value: T) => T;
```

And here's the type of `Form` without the generics, which hopefully makes it easier to understand.

```
type FormType = ( props: FormProps ) => React.ReactElement;
```